Unable to calculate Thevenin resistance
I have to solve for the Thevenin Resistance for the following question and I am unable to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

When calculating the Thevenin resistance, I shorted the voltage source. Now, looking from the perspective of terminals A and B, it seems like the 100 and 200 ohm resistors are series and they are parralel to the 150 ohm resistor. (100 + 200)//150
$$\left(\frac{1}{100 + 200} + \frac{1}{150}\right)^{-1} = 100\Omega$$
Unfortunately, this answer turns out to be incorrect. The correct answer is 60 ohms
I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks!

The 200 ohm resistor is a red herring. It's in parallel with a voltage source with 0 internal resistance. You should disregard it. By red herring I mean it's a silly complication to a simple problem. Your calculation of the Thevenin resistance started out correctly but you included the 200 ohm resistor which was shorted out along with the 5 volt source.
By "disregard" I mean solve the problem as if the 200 ohm resistor wasn't there. No matter what value it has, its parallel combination with an ideal voltage source is just that voltage source.
The object in finding Thevenin and Norton equivalents is to find a voltage source in series with a resistor (Thevenin) or a current source in  parallel with a resistor (Norton) whose open circuit voltages and short circuit currents are the same as the network you're simplifying.
Once you erase the 200 ohm resistor, you're left with a simple voltage divider. At a glance the open circuit voltage is 3V, and the short circuit current 50 Ma. So the series resistor (Thenenin) and parallel resistor (Norton) is 60 ohms. HTH.

I was taught differently...  Maybe you can omit the 200 ohm resistor.  But, now I'm curious.
As I understand, a Thevenin model is supposed to reduce a circuit such that you can model how the Thevenin Volage will move across some input; a load resistor, between some output terminal pair (A & B).  Regardless of whether you're developing a Thevenin or Norton model, the systems overall impedance is reduce and calculated using the same set of rules.
In this case, I was taught to connect the nodes (A & B) between the terminal pair; which here, would short out the 150 ohm resistor.  From there I'd calculate the parallel resistance between the 200 and 100 ohm resistor because both impeding elements cease at node B.  I would then get a Thevenin resistance of 66.667 ohms.
I'm curious where you sourced the quote for 60 ohms. I've noticed that some educational software or textbooks will give sightly different answers regarding how to calculate results for linear systems.  My theory is the  programmed resources I've used will round values that are either,
A) decimal values below 1 or...
B) irrational numbers
I think it's because some programs favor rounding into full integers and or avoid operations that look like division.  However, that's a tangent and could be completely unrelated; you might've gotten your quote directly from an instructor idk.
But if I've remember things correctly that'd be my two cents!

I'm sure you weren't taught differently. The red herrring resistor is extremely common in homework problems. You should check Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. Search on "thevenin" and you'll find many questions about the deliberate misdirection.. (None of them use "red herring," unless it's one of my answers.)  You don't have to memorize a formula to find a thevenin equivalent. A very good way is to find  it is to determine the open circuit voltage (no load VAB), and short circuit current (current thru an AB shunt). In this problem Voc = Vth = 3v. Isc = 50 mA. Rth (Ohm's law) = 60 ohms.
